# ¿Cómo puedo modificar parámetros dentro de un .txt desde java por medio del FileOutputStream?

Tags: java

El asunto es ese, tengo un .txt que le cambié la extensión a .properties precisamente para manipularlo dentro del aplicativo.

Mediante `FileInputStream` puedo consultarlos así:

```
try {
    /*configuracion.properties es el nombre del archivo ubicado en:
    C:\Users\Gerencia\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LectorParametros
    */
    configInput = new FileInputStream("configuracion.properties");
    config.load(configInput);
    System.out.println(config.getProperty("usuario"));
    System.out.println(config.getProperty("clave"));
} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error LEYENDO configuración\n" + e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Ahora quiero modificarlos, he intentado con `FileOutputStream` así:

```
try {
    configOutput = new FileOutputStream("configuracion.properties");
    config.setProperty("usuario", "andres");
    config.setProperty("clave", "123456");
} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error MODIFICANDO configuración\n" + e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Pero lo que hace es eliminarme todo lo que tengo dentro del archivo. ¿Que puedo hacer?

**Muchas gracias.**

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu código. ¿Qué es `config`?. Quiero suponer que es un objeto tuyo. En cualquier caso, lo que haces al **modificar**, realmente lo estás recreando y si no lo cierras con la función `close` de `configOutput` no guardara los cambios pequeños, si lo necesitas posteriormente y no puedes cerrarlo, puedes usar la función `flush`. Pero en resumen siempre debes de llamar la función `close` cuando termines de utilizarlo.

Comment: Si ejecutas el segundo bloque de código en solitario, efectivamente le dices al FOS que escriba un archivo con ese nombre y ese contenido, así que al FOS nunca le das como insumo el contenido anterior. Usa los dos bloques, carga primero lo que ya está, reemplaza lo que quieres modificar y luego guarda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta guardarlo después de setear las propiedades:

`config.store(configOutput, "Sin comentarios");`